# Metro areas with the biggest daytime bulge in population?

Tags: factoids, cruising

Juneau, Alaska has a population of roughly 30,000. During the day, according to a taxi driver I utilized, cruise ships can bring in about 10,000 people. So during the day, the number of people in Juneau can increase by 33%. That's a pretty big "daytime bulge" in the population and it makes me wonder what metro areas have larger "daytime bulges".

I guess you can experience a similar phenomenon with employment. ie. lots of people commuting into town for their day job. But I imagine most of these people live in the same *metro area* even if they don't live in the same *city*.

Comment: I saw an article recently (but can't find it now) about Dubrovnik, saying their population can double when there are multiple cruise ships in port. It's become very a popular destination, in part because the HBO TV show "Game of Thrones" was filmed there.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is a practical problem related to travel; it doesn't even relate to travel or commute times as that depends not merely on the number of people but on the efficiency of the local transport network.

Comment: @MikeHarris the problem in Dubrovnik was already significant before Game of Thrones began, however.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable.  There likely isn't any systematic data collection on this.

Comment: @gerrit You can compare the regular population vs. the number of tourists that come in.

Comment: @Max Sure, but who measures daytime visits and how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.

Answer (score 3):

By percentage, a fair guess would be Vatican City. It has a [population of 1000](https://www.google.ca/search?q=population%20of%20vatican%20city&oq=population%20of%20vatican&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.7591j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and sees as many as [20000 tourists per day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourism_in_Vatican_City), so it bulges by 1900%.

Comment: I'd consider Vatican City to be part of the Rome metropolitan area, population several million.

Comment: Fair point but it is unclear if there is a true definition of metro area and if one would count as crossing international borders.

Comment: Whittier, Alaska, has a population of 205 and is a cruise-ship destination.  If two ships come in at the same time, it can rival Vatican City for growth with no questions of "metropolitan area".  Other Alaskan candidates are Skagway (1100 people, four cruise ship docks to Whittier's one) and Seward (2700 people, three docks).

Answer (score -2):

I imagine that Venice has the biggest day population bulge, both from cruise ships and regular tourists .

Comment: Since the question explicitly specified _metro area_, I would imagine Mestre and other parts of the mainland would count too -- so it's not clear that "regular tourists" wound constitute a significant "day bulge". For one, tourists who stay on the mainland and commute to Venice proper would still be staying in the metro area; for another the metro area [has some 800.000 regular inhabitants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_City_of_Venice).

Comment: [citation needed]